# “failed to load session “Ubuntu”" on virtualbox ubuntu guest

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04

I  have a  corrupt guest  install of ubuntu 12.04 running on virtualbox 4.2.6.  I  cannot  boot  to graphical mode . I  get  an error “failed to load session “Ubuntu”" How  can I remove  information from the  virtual disk or  repair it? Networking is also disabled

Answer (score 0):

Try moving /etc/X11/xorg.conf to a /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup.

I think the correct syntax would be :

sudo service lightdm stop ,
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup ,
sudo service lightdm start , or sudo init 6 to restart the machine

The system will recreate xorg.conf by itself...

Of course, if you don't see the login screen, use alt+ctrl+f1 - f6